# Multiple IP interfaces responding to SNMP query in a same router?

Tags: router, ip, snmp

How to configure multiple IP address in a router . My requirement is both address should respond to SNMP query

Comment: +1 to @bubu. What is your router?

Answer (score 1):

That largely depends on how you configure your router / what your router is running.

You can e.g. create virtual eth interfaces in linux (eth0, eth0:1, etc.)

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address [ip]
netmask [netmask]
```

Then specify and bind the snmpd address in the snmpd configuration

```
OPTIONS="-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -a -x 127.0.0.1 [ip]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply specify `udp:` to listen on all interfaces. I.e.

```
OPTIONS="-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -a -x udp: "
```